# moving std::vector to std::array

Tags: c++

`std::vector` and `std::array` store their data in contiguous blocks of memory. Suppose I have

```cpp
class T;    // A movable class
T t;
std::vector<T>  vec;
vec.push_back(t);

std::array<T,1> arr;
```

Assuming like above that I am guaranteed to know that `vec` and `arr` have the same length. Is there a way that I can **move** `vec` to `array` instead of copy it with `std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr.begin())`?

Comment: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span) (C++20) might interest you.

Comment: This migth be an _XY problem_. Could you specify what problem you are trying to solve with that.

Comment: Note that you cannot move objects in C++. You can only move their content. An array will always have its own objects-elements and a vector also its own, and both will be distinct. You cannot make the vector elements to be owned/managed by an array object. Span might be a solution as suggested (but we don't know what is the use case).

Answer (score 11):

You cannot move the vector. But you can move each element of the vector:

```
std::move(vec.begin(), vec.end(), arr.begin());
```

Comment: Yes, true indeed. And useful if `T` is big. Have an upvote.

Comment: But if elements are `T` as in my example instead of `T*` or `T&` how would that work without copying?

Comment: "But if elements are T as in my example instead of T* or T& how would that work without copying?" I think that if T does have a move contructor / operator implemented properly, then it should avoid copying.

Comment: @ReimundoHeluani you can't have a container of references. Pointers are moved/copied like other objects.

Answer (score 4):

Alas not. Neither `std::vector` nor `std::array` have a mechanism to *attach* a block of memory, or to *detach* a block of memory.

`std::copy` is possibly the most reliable method.

Comment: `std::copy` this C++ standard draft.

Comment: i think it is more than that. A simple picture of a `std::vector` is just a pointer to dynamically allocated memory, while a `std::array` is an array. You also cannot assign contents of a vector to a `T[N]`